# Samba share doesn't follow link properly on linux

Tags: samba

So I have made samba share, and configured it to follow soft links pointing outside the shared directory (specifically `/var/www/html`). I have mounted this share into `/mnt` on second computer. Everything works fine, except that the soft link instead of redirecting me to `/mnt/html` on local machine and `/var/www/html` on server, it instead redirects me to local `/var/www/html`.

Is there a way I could fix that?

Comment: See if your samba configuration matches the ones [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/how-do-you-make-samba-follow-symlink-outside-the-shared-path)

Comment: @George the configuration seems to be matching, I do believe it may be client wise problem, as I could access that location without any problem on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that this problem only occurs if the partition is mounted via `mount` command. If using GUI this problem doesn't happen.

When mounting via `mount` the client will see a link instead of folder. When mounted by GUI the client sees a regular folder instead of link, and therefore when this folder is opened the link is followed on server rather than on client.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have created an absolute symlink rather than a relative one. Try creating one by passing a relative path to *ln* when you create the symlink.